# CORS Policy Error when using Laravel 7 on production server

Tags: php, laravel, cors

I'm on Laravel 7 and i get the error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/lmvworker.min.js' from origin 'https://my.site.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' that is not equal to the supplied origin.
```

It's working on localhost but when i go on the production server the error shows up.

I don't understand why 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is set to 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' when on production server.

This is my **config/cors.php** (i tried also 'paths' => ['*'])

```
'paths' => [],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => false,

'max_age' => false,

'supports_credentials' => false,
```

**Http/Kernel.php**

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\SetLocale::class
];
```

**config/app.php**

```
'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    ...
    ...
    Fruitcake\Cors\CorsServiceProvider::class
],
```

Comment: Perhaps you are manually setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `http://127.0.0.1:8000` somewhere else and this middleware just isn't running. Try searching your codebase in production for `http://127.0.0.1:8000`.

Comment: i already did and found nothing

Answer (score 1):

Note: For allowed_origins you must include the scheme when not using a wildcard, eg. ['http://example.com', 'https://example.com']. You must also take into account that the scheme will be present when using allowed_origins_patterns.

Reference: https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors#options

Comment: i tried with `'allowed_origins' => ['https://my.site.com'],` but it doesn't work